# Codeigniter cart remove a single element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, cart

i have been trying to remove a single element from my cart using jQuery so it doesn't load the page but i am unable to detect where i am missing something. Its removing the element , but looks like something is wrong with jQuery so its loading the page.
Here are the code snaps -

View-

```
        <td class="remove">
            <?php echo anchor('home/remove_cart/'.$item['rowid'],'X',$item['rowid']); ?>
        </td>
```

Controller-

```
    public function remove_cart($rowid) {
        $this->cart->update(array(
            'rowid'=>$rowid,
            'qty' => 0
    ));

    redirect(base_url().'home/purchase_order');  
}
```

js-

```
    $("td.remove").live("click", function() {
        var rem = $('a.removecart').data();
        alert(rem+"f");
        $.get(link + "home/remove_cart", {rowid : rem} ,function(data) {
            $.get(link + "home/show_cart", function(home) {
            $("#cart_content").html(home);
        });
    });

    return false;
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Also, you're using a long time deprecated jQuery version. The use of live() and bind() were replaced with on()  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: actually i tried with both , but its all same result
I am actually implementing here a cart system , where on cart menu there can be certain product , so i updated add to cart or empty cart using jQuery thats fine , so last part is , removing a single element from the cart . so all is happening is its removing the item but its also loading the pages , so jQuery is somewhat error here , but couldn't find :/

Comment: Where's the error happening? All I can see is when you receive the response from the server after requesting it to remove the cart item, you do another request, no matter the response, to fetch the complete html code for the cart. Where is it failing? By the way you could do it all with a single ajax request.

Comment: Failing means , my target process is not being fulfilled,using jQuery my target thing is to load the cart without refreshing pages, but in here its always loading page when the request is made

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a click event to the link's parent. So you must first of all cancel the default bahaviour of the link when you click on it. Then the click event will naturally bubble up to its parent: td.remove. The link will not be followed, and the click handler for the td will be executed.

```
    $("td.remove a").live("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("td.remove").live("click", function() {
        var rem = $('a.removecart').data();
        alert(rem+"f");
        $.get(link + "home/remove_cart", {rowid : rem} ,function(data) {
            $.get(link + "home/show_cart", function(home) {
            $("#cart_content").html(home);
        });
    });
```

If this won't work, provide with more information, since there's a return false at the end that I don't know where it comes from.